# ImageResizer subfolders how to choose

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, imageresizer

We are using ImageResizer plugin with Diskcahce plugin for caching, http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache.

Our web sites uses millions of image. Total size of all the images is close to 2 TB.

So to maintain disk caching, how many subfolders do we have to specify?

As per the documentation I have read here : http://imageresizing.net/plugins/diskcache

```
given a desired cache size of 100,000 items, this should be set to 256.
```

But in our case, cache size will be quite more.
Can we use this plugin ? 
If yes, how many subfolders do we have to use?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Set the subfolders count to  ((max images)/400), then round up to the nearest power of two. `16387` will support around 6 million images. You're going to have a hard time scaling NTFS past 4 million or so; the Windows filesystem gets bogged down.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, Prefer "Proxy" of images.
The proxy will be faster (no ASP.net Serverside code will be used) than create and fill a large folder of rarely-accessed files and manage it.

IIS Proxy, Varnish Proxy, NGINX,  or any other proxy can maintain  a cache, and It will works better than imageresizer/asp.net-mvc.